# Skip or ignore the particular row concept in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables TABLE1 with columns ROLLNO, STATUS, ROOMNO, STNAME and TABLE2 with columns ROLLNO, STATUS & ROOMNO.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
( 
    ROLLNO NUMBER(3), 
    STATUS VARCHAR2(2), 
    ROOMNO VARCHAR2(4), 
    STNAME VARCHAR2(3)
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 
(
    ROLLNO NUMBER(3), 
    STATUS VARCHAR2(2), 
    ROOMNO VARCHAR2(4)
);
```

Data present in the tables TABLE1 and TABLE2 are:

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (100, '00', '1234', 'SOM');
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (101, '01', '1423', 'TOM');
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (102, '02', '1324', 'SAM');
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (103, '03', '4321', 'DOM');
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (104, '04', '', 'RAM');
 -----------------------------------------------------
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (100,'00', '');
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (101,'01', '1423');
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (102,'02', '');
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (103,'03', '4321');
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (104,'04', '');
```

I want to select the columns ROLLNO and STNAME from TABLE1 by finding the common values of STATUS and ROOMNO columns from both the tables and if ROOMNO is null, I want to skip/ignore so it won't effect result data.

This is the query I  have used and not sure what query to be use to ignore/skip the rows if ROOMNO is null.

```
SELECT T1.ROLLNO, T1.STNAME
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.STATUS = T2.STATUS AND T1.ROOMNO = T2.ROOMNO
```

By querying the above result, I was able to get required result but if ROOMNO value is NULL from TABLE1 or TABLE2, I want to skip that particular row or do we need to use CASE WHEN concept. I am not sure.

Comment: Well, that query *is* skipping rows if ROOMNO is NULL. It returns ROLLNOs 101 and 103. What did you expect to get as a result?

Comment: If multiple rows(lets say 1Million rows) are present in TABLE1 and TABLE2 and due to above query, if 1 row is having ROOMNO as null.. because of this row, we are not able to send the entire result data...So I am looking for a query to use ignore/skip statement for the particular row having ROOMNO as Null so it won't effect other rows data

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand it. Maybe - if you posted what result you expect (as I previously asked) - it would be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a relational database NULL does not equal anything, not even another NULL.
You can think of this as implying that your join clause, which includes `T1.ROOMNO = T2.ROOMNO`, is logically equivalent to:

```
T1.ROOMNO is not null and 
T2.ROOMNO is not null and 
T1.ROOMNO = T2.ROOMNO
```

So your query is already filtering out null values of T1.ROOMNO and T2.ROOMNO as required.